# Bootstrap table - How to assign width 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I make a web site with a bootstrap table. There are a rows, with columns, each row with a edit button. To load the table show any columns and hide others.

When It click in the button open a window-moddal with the data of this row. There is a little problem: when the column is hidden doesn't show the info because I use the method POST.

My idea is give to width 0 to the hidden columns, the data will be in the web site but the 0 of the width.

My code:

```
<table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod'
                                   data-toggle='table'
                                   data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                   data-show-refresh='true'
                                   data-show-toggle='true'
                                   data-sort-name='name'
                                   data-sort-order='desc'
                                   data-show-columns='true'
                                   data-pagination='true'
                                   data-search='true'>

                        <thead class='thead-inverse'>
                            <tr>  
                                <th data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
                                <th data-switchable='false'></th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>EDICIÓ</th>  
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PÀG.</th>  
                                <th data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>CODI</th>  
                                <th data-switchable='false'>IMATGE</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>DESCRIPCIÓ CAT</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>DESCRIPCIÓ ESP</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true'>MARCA</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true'>GRAMATJE</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>DESTACAT</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-CAT</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-LEV</th> 
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-AND</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-CEN</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-NOR</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-VAS</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true'>PVP-SPAR</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>USER</th>
                                <th data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>FECHA-MOD</th>
                                <th data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
```

this load data from php script...

The hidden columns doesn't show the values of the window modal. I think that a solution is show all columns but any columns with width 0, the efect is the same that hidden columns.

My code to add values in the modal-window:

```
/* EDIT MODAL WINDOW */

            $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                  var $button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                  var row = $button.closest("tr"), // edit button is in the same row as data you want to change
                  $tds = row.find("td"); // get all table cells in that row

                  $.each($tds, function(index,value) {

                    var field = $(this).data("field");

                    console.log($(this).text());

                    $('[name="' + field +'"]').val($(this).text()); //input name in the modal window
                  });

                 var src_value = $tds.closest("td").find('img').attr('src');
                 $('[name="imagen"]').attr("src",src_value);

            });
```

And from other php file update the database:

```
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$edicion = $_POST['edicion'];
$pagina = $_POST['pagina'];
$descripcion_esp = $_POST['descripcion_esp'];
$descripcion_cat = $_POST['descripcion_cat'];
$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$gramaje = $_POST['gramaje'];
$destacado= $_POST['destacado'];
$pvp_cat = $_POST['pvp_cat'];
$pvp_lev = $_POST['pvp_lev'];
$pvp_and = $_POST['pvp_and'];
$pvp_cen = $_POST['pvp_cen'];
$pvp_nor = $_POST['pvp_nor'];
$pvp_vas = $_POST['pvp_vas'];
$pvp_spar = $_POST['pvp_spar'];

$query = "UPDATE....."
```

How to change the width of the columns of the bootstrap-table?

Comment: You could use `<input type="hidden">` to get the hidden data to be included in a form submission.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is not the hidden input fields. I update my ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the problem but if you just want to hide a column you could use `data-visible` :

```
<th data-visible="false">Column</th>
```

I've a workaround for your case, just hide the columns using `data-visible` as shows in above code then show them when you want to iterate the tds using :

```
$('table').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'columnName');
```

And when you close the modal hide them again :

```
$('table').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'columnName');
```

You could show all the hidden column using `each()` method with `.bootstrapTable('getHiddenColumns')` :

```
$.each($('table').bootstrapTable('getHiddenColumns'), function (key, column) {
    $('table').bootstrapTable('showColumn', column['field']);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not explain well. To open the modal-window do not show the values of the fields that hidden columns of the table. I do not know to show al values of the table in window-modal although of the hidden columns. Another solution it will be launch a php query when it open the modal window.

Comment: How you show data in modal? please add more code so we an better understood the situation here..

Comment: I use javascript to show the values. And I make a php page to updated values of database using POST method when click the button of the window -modal, it's working fine. The problem is in the fields without values....I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks @Zakaria Acharki. It seems a good idea, I will try it ;)

Comment: A question: how to it the method to the close modal-window?

Comment: Use `$('#edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {`

Comment: I have tried to insert this code: $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'descripcion_esp'); at $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) but it does not work.

Comment: Exactly, Could you explain me this method?

Comment: It will show the column you specify in the name, as you show in the comment it should show the `description_esp` column when you click on `#edit`... wait i'll provide an example

Comment: it's working! Thanks for all ;) I have seen all methods of bootstrap-table, with this I could solved my demands. I'm using JSON.stringify($('table').bootstrapTable('getHiddenColumns')) to know that columns are hidden and after that it show it. Only a question, this method returns a JSON string, How do it to go a specific parameter? (Ex: value descripcion_es)

Comment: Yes it's an option but also it will be an option to use showAllColumns method. I'm try it but at moment doesn't works.